# Why am I being encouraged to start a bounty, but cannot do so?

Tags: support, bug, bounty

In my list of questions, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650282/why-does-adding-datatables-break-my-page) has as a superscription "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

I would like to start a bounty for that question (as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646320/how-can-i-show-a-subset-of-data-on-pie-pieces-in-chart-js-while-still-displaying)), but I am not being afforded that opportunity.

Why not? Why am I being encouraged to do something, when that is apparently for some reason not possible?

### UDPATE

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to start bounties. Whatt exactly appears when you try so?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the "start a bounty" link under the question comments?

Comment: It is not there; hence the problem. I have started many bounties, and I am well aware of the process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty *"Users may only have three active bounties at any given time."*

Comment: Have you considered instead editing your questions to be more presentable? we don't need an UPDATE header every time you change something, your changes should be integrated into the question so that it looks like the information was there to begin with. We can see what was added when with the edit history. And... read the documentation... both for your SO questions and SO Meta questions...

Comment: ... why would anyone add a bounty to that question... (the one in the screenshot) it's a typo question..

Comment: To reward the answerer.

Comment: for answering an off-topic question?

Comment: For solving the problem; that is the real purpose of an answer,or should be.

Comment: If the problem isn't going to be useful to future visitors though, the answer probably won't be either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've already got three bounties active.  [You can't have any more active bounties beyond that.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

[image]

Once one of those is awarded, you can create another one.

Comment: Okay, so it is a bug that it encourages me to activate a bounty when that is not possible (yet).